# I still can decrypt the file after I modified the private key

Tags: openssl, encryption

When I tried to use openssl to encrypt my data, I got confused.

First, I created a self-signed cert and the corresponding private key with the following command:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -x509 -nodes -days 36500 -outform PEM -keyout Private.PEM -out Cert.PEM
```

Then, I use the cert to encrypt my file with the following command:

```
openssl smime -encrypt -aes-256-cbc -binary -outform DER -in MyFile.zip -out MyFile.zip.enc Cert.PEM
```

Finally, I can decrypt the encrypted data with this:

```
openssl smime -decrypt -binary -inform DER -in MyFile.zip.enc -out MyFile.Decrypted.zip -inkey Private.PEM
```

However, I opened the private key (Private.PEM) and substitude one char with another, save it, reissue the third command, I can still decrypte the file!

Is this supposed to happen, (the PEM format is error tolerant?), or my procedure is wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Which character did you change? I get the following error when I tried - 

unable to load signing key file
8516:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1319:
8516:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:381:Type=PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO
8516:error:0907B00D:PEM routines:PEM_READ_BIO_PRIVATEKEY:ASN1 lib:pem_pkey.c:132:

Comment: As per my understanding, it should not work.